# How to drop a table (sqlite3) in Django==2.1?

Tags: django, django-models, sqlite

I created the following models in my app `events` :

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse


class EventType(models.Model):
    type_of_event = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type_of_event


class Event(models.Model):
    type_of_event = models.ForeignKey(EventType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    event_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    entry_fee = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Due to some errors and changes, I created and deleted the migration file many times. Now, the makemigrations command works but when I try to migrate the models using : `python manage.py migrate` , it shows the following error:

```
  File "/home/anirudh/.local/share/virtualenvs/Amrita-event-manager-DHqKHtGE/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 294, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "events_event" already exists
```

I am using django version 2.1 along with sqlite3.

Most questions similar to this were too old and incompatible to the version I am using now.

Comment: Delete the database file. SQLite creates a file that contains the (entire) database, so by removing it, you "drop" the database.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Do you mean the db.sqlite3 file? But if I delete this, won't it affect my other models in other apps?

Comment: yes you will remove all data (in all apps), unless you did some advanced routing. But right now, you likely brought your database in an inconsistent state (where some migrations are listed, or partially applied). You can also open the sqlite shell, and aim to remove the `events_event` table.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you suggest a way by which I can delete just the `events_event` table. I don't want to affect my other models. I searched for a way to do that on StackOverflow, but most solutions were too old.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> First of all, make a backup of the file db.sqlite3

You could use dbshell, which runs the command-line client for the database engine

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dbshell

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

list all tables

```
sqlite> .table
```

delete table

```
sqlite> DROP TABLE <table>;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm ;)